# Trying to identify an (OEM?) analogue video USB capture board with <GsubR> logo

Tags: analog, identification, usb-device

I am trying to diagnose a scientific instrument with a USB bus fault.

It has a built-in analogue video camera which produces a CVBS output.  This drives the small double-sided header board I am trying to identify.

The header board has three main chips; A SAA7113H which converts the analogue video to a digital data stream and a Zoran ZR36504 chip which converts the digital video stream to USB with the aid of a GLT440L16 DRAM which is uses to buffer the outgoing video data.

The header board is marked with silkscreen legend "IGA821".  Googling that provided a single possibly relevant link on a PC device driver file site for "usb video genie capture device", but that was all.

The board has a silkscreen logo which I could not identify on any of the manufacturer logo websites I know of. It comprises a G-subscript-R legend enclosed in a diamond/angle-brackets.

It is probably a long shot with the instrument being around 10 years old but I am hoping that if the manufacturer can be identified, the board which I suspect is an OEM part might still be available somewhere.

Here are some photos including a close-up of the  logo.

[image: GR logo]

[image: Photo no.1 of header board].

[image: Photo no.2 of header board].

[image: Photo no.3 of header board].

[image: Photo no.4 of header board].

Does anybody recognise it?

My thanks to Hobbs for his research and useful answer below.

Some additional follow-up information: On a host PC the board shows up on the USB bus as Vendor ID=0x0768 (Camtel Technology Corp.) and Device ID=0x0010 which does not appear in any USB DBs I looked in, e.g. https://the-sz.com/products/usbid/index.php?v=0x0768.  Curiously none of the Video Genie devices he mentioned are listed either.

Many thanks

Tom Crane

Answer (score 0):

Researching on "USB Video Genie", I found a Taiwanese company called "Camtel" (now defunct) that made the [USB Video Genie IGA-801 and IGA-802](https://web.archive.org/web/20050214085553/http://www.camtel.com.tw/usb_video-genie.htm). Perhaps the IGA-821 was the model number of the [USB Video Genie Pro](https://web.archive.org/web/20050214085916/http://www.camtel.com.tw/usb_video_genie_pro.htm) which doesn't seem to have any publicly-referenced model number. Or perhaps it was just a later revision of the 801. It's not the [USB 2.0 Video Genie Pro](https://web.archive.org/web/20050211040514/http://www.camtel.com.tw/usb2.0-video-genie.htm), since the Zoran chip is definitely only USB 1.1. In either case, it seems like too close a match to be a coincidence.

Presumably then, the silkscreen logo isn't "GR" but "CT"... something. Could be CTR but I can't imagine what the R stands for. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same board in a microscope to evaluate the quality of optical connectors "westover fibercheck". VIN and PID identifiers are different. probably the board is really OEM and the identifier is in the I2C chip. I also have problems with its performance, although the drivers are installed normally and the target software sees this equipment, but does not receive a picture..

Comment: In the end, after a lot of effort, I gave up trying to fix this board.  There was an SDK that went with the Zoran chip and I had a hunch that the board probably fairly closely followed examples in the SDK.  I had in mind to make an approximate clone of the board using the SDK to use as a replacement, thus avoiding potentially damaging my existing and working (albeit poorly) board.  I even tried contacting the former CEO of Zoran Corp. for information but w/o success.

Comment: The (Windows XP) application that goes with the instrument exposes a DirectShow interface and so my current fix/approach is to use an off-the-shelf analogue video capture stick and configure the application to use that instead. HTH. Tom Crane